# Jobrunr Server Count Decreasing

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, jobrunr

I have 3 pods in EKS and 1 task in ECR connected to the same postgresql database. Since each of these will be considered a "server" on it's own, I expected a minimum of 4 jobrunr background servers. But seems that at times this just drops to 1. Also during this time, the job processing is paused. Jobs in enqueued state stays enqueued, processing stays at processing and so forth.
I have faced this multiple times but have failed to identify any triggers that may be causing this. I went through the logs for the time and it seems backgroundserver.stop() function was called. I am not able to identify from where this is getting called. (There are two functions which can trigger the call but the logs from those functions were not printed.) The only common thing I can find is it has something to do with deployment. Not in every deployment do we face the issue, but around the time jobrunr got stuck, every time we have had a deployment.

On another note, would love to know how jobrunr identifies the number of servers it should be running and if we have any control over the same.